# livecode Installing app on target - Android

Tags: livecode

I have a very simple test that I am doing in Livecode Community 6.5, on Windows 8.1.
I have created a button which shows a dialog window when clicked on.

When I run the test in an emulator, the dialog window Standalone Builder Progress reaches the stage "Installing application on target device and then" gets stuck.
Each time I have to terminate LiveCode in the Task Manager. I have tried changing the device but got the same results.

From Android Studio I can see the device when I start AVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the Platform version of the AVD is the same or higher than the Minimum Android Version in the Standalone Application Settings of your stack.

---

Try in addition to:

1. install the latest stable version of LC 6.6.2 from here: [LC downloads](http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode/)
2. make sure you have the Android SDK running with SDK Tools revision 22.6.3 (rev. 23 may not work properly and needs some workaround)
3. try with using Android 2.3.3 (API 10) - install both SDK Platform and Google APIs
4. in the Standalone Settings select "Sign for development only" and "Allow External Storage"
5. if you changed the "Identifier" (default shows as "com.yourcompany.yourapp"), make sure that its contents does not contain any  "-" and "&" since they are not working there; possibly change to default.
6. create a standalone android app (apk) and try to install it on a real device

Comment: Yes i double checked it.

Comment: Yes i double checked it. Android 2.2, API level 8

Comment: @user1264748 see my additions above

Comment: I have downloaded LC 6.6.2, tried API10, Set for external storage and changed the identifier getting same the issue. Downloaded the APK and tried installing it on the emulator. Getting error Application not installed.

Comment: I have just setup Android deployment for LiveCode on a fresh Win 8.1 bootcamp and unfortunately cannot replicate the issue you are experiencing. Could you supply a link to your stack. This would allow us to rule out any potential stack specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you to everyone who helped.

I think 2 things have to be there in order for it to work.
unique Identifier & external storage

Thanks